# Vuex state no showing in Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a Laravel installation and want to use vuejs for the fornt-end. So, I ran npm install --save vuex and all the installation was successful.

The in app.js ( /resources/js/app.js ) I imported the store file and added it to the vue instance object:

```
import store from './store/store'

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    store
});
```

Inside store.js I have the following:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

import jobs from './modules/jobs'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
        jobs
    }
});
```

The jobs.js (store/modules/jpbs.js):

```
const state = {
    value: 1,
    jobs: [
        { name: 'Milton', age: '23'}
    ]
}

const getters = {
    jobs: state => {
        return state.jobs;
    },
    value: state => {
        return state.value;
    }
}

//EDITED
export default {
    state,
    getters
};
```

Ultimately, I tried to test how things go if I get anything from the state or getter:

```
    <button type="button" class="btn bgDark mt-2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
    Add New {{ this.$store.state.value }}
    </button>
```

When I visit my site, the value does not show and I dont see errors in the console.

Is there perhaps anything I missed in the vuex configuration?

Comment: Unless you omitted some of your `modules/jobs.js` file, you are missing an export of your module.

Comment: Actually yes, the export was missing and I just updated my question. I still dont see the value from the state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to get the value from your jobs.js module you need the to reference it like this:

`this.$store.state.jobs.value`

( the *this* is optional)

If you look at the first example in the [Vuex Documents](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html) - The last two lines of code are

```
store.state.a
store.state.b
```

where a and b are the module names (jobs in your case)

Comment: All right, so I use: return this.$store.state.jobs.value;
All right, so it should always be $store, then (state,getters), the module name and then the property?

Comment: Yes, unless you use the mapState or mapGetters helpers, which allows you to map to a variable name: `...mapState({                             
                value: state => state.jobs.value
            })` Now you can call `this.value` all over the place

Answer (score 0):

`this` should not be used within html templates, Vue automatically assumes that variables or objects written within brackets `{{ }}` are attributes of `this`.